# Header only on first page, smaller margins on subsequent pages with multicol and landscape

Tags: header-footer, margins, multicol, landscape

My current code is below. I want the header in this landscape document only on the first page, and not on any subsequent pages. Furthermore, I want to remove the big gap that happens when I suppress the header on subsequent pages. Thus, what I currently do, is end multicol after the first page, then define a newgeometry that applies to subsequent pages. This has the disadvantage, that I have to manually fill the first page, then apply the end multicol and newgeometry. Overall this seems like a hacky solution.

Does anyone have an idea how to make this code more elegant?
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}% before geometry!
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\uselandscape}{%
  \clearpage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}%switch to landscape
  \newgeometry{% geometry settings for landscape
    left=0.3in, right=0.3in, top=0.9in, bottom=0.8in,headheight=23pt
  }%
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
    \fancyhead[L]{Header\\Header 2 (last updated \today)}
}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\uselandscape

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\section{Preferences and Choice}
\hangpara{1em}{1}\textbf{Rational preference relation} the preference relation $\succsim$ is rational iff it satisfies 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Completeness: $\forall x,y, x\succsim y$ or $y \succsim x$
    \item Transitivity: $\forall x,y,z, x\succsim y$ and $y \succsim z \implies x\succsim z$ 
    \end{enumerate}
If $\succsim$ is rational, then 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\succ$ is both irreflexive ($x\succ x$ never holds) and transitive (if $x\succ y$ and $y\succ z$ then $x\succ z$)
    \item $\forall x,y,z, x\succsim y$ and $y \succsim z \implies x\succsim z$ 
    \item if $x\succ y \succsim z,$ then $x\succ z$
    \end{enumerate}
    

\end{multicols*} % end multicols after first page to define newgeometry for all subsequent pages

\newgeometry{% newgeometry settings for subsequent pages: top margin 0.1in and no header
    left=0.3in, right=0.3in, top=0.1in, bottom=0.7in,headheight=0pt,includehead
  }%
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\hangpara{1em}{1}\textbf{An Unnumbered Paragraph} aaa
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler code works for me.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}% before geometry!
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\uselandscape}{%
  \clearpage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}%switch to landscape
  \newgeometry{% geometry settings for landscape
    left=0.3in, right=0.3in, top=0.9in, bottom=0.8in,headheight=23pt
  }%
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
    \fancyhead[L]{Header\\Header 2 (last updated \today)}
}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\uselandscape

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\section{Preferences and Choice}
\hangpara{1em}{1}\textbf{Rational preference relation} the preference relation $\succsim$ is rational iff it satisfies 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Completeness: $\forall x,y, x\succsim y$ or $y \succsim x$
    \item Transitivity: $\forall x,y,z, x\succsim y$ and $y \succsim z \implies x\succsim z$ 
    \end{enumerate}
If $\succsim$ is rational, then 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\succ$ is both irreflexive ($x\succ x$ never holds) and transitive (if $x\succ y$ and $y\succ z$ then $x\succ z$)
    \item $\forall x,y,z, x\succsim y$ and $y \succsim z \implies x\succsim z$ 
    \item if $x\succ y \succsim z,$ then $x\succ z$
    \end{enumerate}
    

%\end{multicols*} % end multicols after first page to define newgeometry for all subsequent pages

\newpage
\newgeometry{% newgeometry settings for subsequent pages: top margin 0.0in and no header
    left=0.3in, right=0.3in, top=0.0in, bottom=0.7in,headheight=0pt,includehead
  }%
%\begin{multicols*}{3}

\hangpara{1em}{1}\textbf{An Unnumbered Paragraph} aaa

\newpage

\hangpara{1em}{1}\textbf{Another Unnumbered Paragraph} bbb


\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image: new]

Comment: Thanks, while that works I'd like to reduce the top margin on subsequent pages. See image for what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/35GH5K5.png

Comment: @Eulerian I updated the answer. You have to apply geometry again and it will be valid for all subsequent pages.